# vue: validation errors displays when created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, yup, vee-validate

I have a registration form where the user can select different checkboxes, but he has to check at least one box. I implemented the validation with vee-validate and yup.

The strange thing is, that the validation is checked when the site is rendered and so the errormessages are displayed before the user tries to submit the form. But the errors should only display when the user tries to submit the form without check any boxes.

Here you can see the red error text above the checkboxes. But I have the same implementation in the select-option above of the checkboxes. But there the error shows only when the user submits the form without select an option. There it works correcty.
[image]

**Update**: Here is my code:

```
<Form
  @submit="handleRegistration"
  :validation-schema="schema"
  v-slot="{ errors }">
  <div class="form-group row mt-4">
    <label for="location" class="col-6 col-form-label">
      <strong
        >Im Umkreis von welchem Ort dürfen wir dir GynäkologInnen
        vorschlagen?
      </strong>
     <p class="text-secondary">Beispielsweise Wohn- oder Arbeitsort</p>
</label>
 <div class="col-4 col-form-label">
  <small class="text-danger" v-if="errors.location">
    {{ errors.location }}</small>

  <Field
    name="location"
    as="select"
    v-model="savedForm.location"
    class="form-select"
    aria-label="Default select example">
    <option
      as="input"
      name="location"
      v-for="location in locations"
      :value="location.location_id"
      :key="location.location_id"
      :selected="location === locations.location_id">
      {{ location.location_postal_code }}
      {{ location.location_name }}
    </option>
      </Field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="gender" class="col-6 col-form-label">
      <strong>Gewünschtes Geschlecht? </strong>
      <p class="text-secondary">Mehrere Optionen möglich</p>
    </label>

    <div class="col-4 col-form-label">
      <small class="text-danger" v-if="errors.gender">
        {{ errors.gender }}</small>
      <div
        class="form-check form-check-inline"
        v-for="gender in genders"
        :key="gender.gender_id">

 <Field
      as="input"
      name="gender"
      type="checkbox"
      class="form-check-input"
      :id="gender.gender_id"
      :value="gender.gender_id"
      v-model="savedForm.gender"/>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gender.gender_id">
      {{ gender.gender_name }}</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="language" class="col-6 col-form-label">
      <strong>Gewünschte Sprache/n? </strong>
      <p class="text-secondary">Mehrere Optionen möglich</p>
    </label>
    <small class="text-danger" v-if="errors.language">
      {{ errors.language }}</small>
    <div
      class="form-check form-check-inline"
      v-for="language in languages"
      :key="language.language_id">

 <Field
    as="input"
    name="language"
     type="checkbox"
     class="form-check-input"
     :id="language.language_id"
     :value="language.language_id"
     v-model="savedForm.language"/>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="language.language_id">
        {{ language.language_name }}</label>
    </div>
      </div>
      <hr />

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-6 col-form-label">
      <strong>Interessierte Spezialgebiete? </strong>
      <p class="text-secondary">Mehrere Optionen möglich</p>
    </label>
    <div
      class="form-check form-check-inline"
      v-for="specialty in specialties"
      :key="specialty.specialty_id">

<Field
    as="input"
    name="specialty"
    type="checkbox"
    class="form-check-input"
    :id="specialty.specialty_id"
    :value="specialty.specialty_id"
    v-model="savedForm.specialty"/>
<label class="form-check-label" for="specialty.specialty_id">
   {{ specialty.specialty_name }}</label>
     </div>
  </div>

  <hr />
     <div class="btn-group col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 offset-5">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="$router.go(-1)">
          Zurück
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-text-center">
          <span v-if="!isLoading">Weiter</span
          ><span v-else class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </Form>

data() {
const schema = yup.object({
  location: yup
    .number()
    .required("Bitte wähle einen Ort")
    .typeError("Bitte wähle einen Ort"),
  gender: yup
    .number()
    .required("Bitte wähle einen Ort")
    .typeError("Bitte wähle einen Ort"),
  language: yup
    .number()
    .required("Bitte wähle mindestens eine Sprache")
    .typeError("Bitte wähle mindestens eine Sprache"),
});
```

Comment: Share your `yup` validation schema and share all code with `form` tag

Comment: You have the same error text in  `required` and `typeError` methods. Сould you please clarify which method gave the error

Comment: Ok, I found out that when I change in the yup schema the type from number() to array() and now the error message shows on load but then disappears after a few seconds..

Comment: And I found out that the .required is showing for a few seconds @VitaliyRayets

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work when I change the yup type to array(). It doesn't validate correcty..

Comment: And when I delete the typeError I receive an error: language must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `[]`).

Comment: So now I have language: yup.number().required("req").typeError("type") and when I load my site it shows "type" in my error message. So there is a mistake..

Comment: I think you must use `v-model`  for two way data binding but you use  `:value` too , why? its incorrect , when you have two-way why you set one-way data binding too!!! Also you can check if type of `savedForm.language`  is `number` by default

Comment: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field#using-v-model

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Thank you for your inputs! I will check this and get back to you